Standard PSU (on HP G1 600 SFF) power adapter to modern 24 pin motherboard
I would like to put in a new motherboard in my system and was wondering if there's an adapter for the current PSU from HP (which seems to have 2 six-pin connectors, and 1 four-pin connector https://www.amazon.com/Li-SUN-Power-Supply-Replacement-ProDesk/dp/B07GSRTDZF)
Meanwhile, the motherboard which I purchased recently (ASUS PRIME B450M-A II) has a 24-pin power plug-in.
I was wondering if I can purchase an adapter to route power from the PSU to the newer motherboard without needing to upgrade the PSU. So far, the only things I can see on Amazon are 24 Pin to 6 Pin connectors for people in situations where they upgrade the PSU and need an adapter to the old HP motherboard.
Is there no other choice but to upgrade the PSU?
CURRENT SPECS:
SanDisk SSD PLUS 240 GB,
7200 RPM HDD 500 GB
2x DDR3 RAM 4 GB
XFX SWFT105 Radeon RX 6400 (note: this only draws 75~ watts of power straight from the PCI slot)
i5 4690
I intend to upgrade my RAM (16 GB of 3200MHz DDR4), CPU (Ryzen 5 5500), and the motherboard (ASUS PRIME B450M-A II)

You might be able to find an adapter but you would have to trust that adapter as it most definitely wouldn’t be official. Much easier to spend a small amount of money and simply replace the PSU.
